# Foundation reInit equalizer throws "_init is not an available method for this element"

Tags: javascript, zurb-foundation-6, foundation-equalizer

I'm using Foundation framework for my website and before updating to Foundation 6.4.3, this syntax Foundation.reInit('equalizer') used to work to re-bind/reflow my plug-ins like Equalizer for my dynamically created elements.

After the update to 6.4.3, it has stopped working and would throw the error in the title "Reference Error: We're Sorry, _init is not an available method for this element". I know for a fact that this used to work because I've used this on my website and it has worked flawlessly up till the update.

I've also tried doing new Foundation.Equalizer($('.eq-div')).applyHeight();
and my browser would just hang and become unresponsive, any reason as to why its doing that?

Any suggestions or help would be appreciated, thanks!